# Unable to access service running in docker swarm cluster

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm cluster with following nodes

```
NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER      ERRORS
manager1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.113:2376           v19.03.12   
worker1    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.114:2376           v19.03.12   
worker2    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.115:2376           v19.03.12
```

I have created service on manager node as follows

```
$ docker service create --name registry --publish 5000:5000 registry:2
```

Now I can access the service from any swarm node

```
$ curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog                                     
{"repositories":[]}
```

But If I try to access the service from outside swarm cluster I get this error

```
$ curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

How can we access service running in swarm cluster from host machine

Comment: Outside of swarm cluster you mean ?

Comment: @MajidRehman Outside of swarm cluster meaning from the host machine where swarm cluster are running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to access service with this command `curl <manager/worker ip>:5000/v2/_catalog`

Answer (score 0):

**PUBLISH A SERVICE’S PORTS USING THE ROUTING MESH**

To publish a service’s ports externally to the swarm, use the --publish : flag. The swarm makes the service accessible at the published port on every swarm node. If an external host connects to that port on any swarm node, the routing mesh routes it to a task. The external host does not need to know the IP addresses or internally-used ports of the service tasks to interact with the service. When a user or process connects to a service, any worker node running a service task may respond. For more details about swarm service networking, see [Manage swarm service networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/).

Example: Run a three-task Nginx service on 10-node swarm
Imagine that you have a 10-node swarm, and you deploy an Nginx service running three tasks on a 10-node swarm:

```
$ docker service create --name my_web \
                        --replicas 3 \
                        --publish published=8080,target=80 \
                        nginx
```

Three tasks run on up to three nodes. You don’t need to know which nodes are running the tasks; connecting to port 8080 on any of the 10 nodes connects you to one of the three nginx tasks. You can test this using curl. The following example assumes that localhost is one of the swarm nodes. If this is not the case, or localhost does not resolve to an IP address on your host, substitute the host’s IP address or resolvable host name.

The HTML output is truncated:

```
$ curl localhost:8080

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...truncated...
</html>
```

Subsequent connections may be routed to the same swarm node or a different one.